# victoria-metrics-k8s-stack with node_exporter

Tags: prometheus-node-exporter, victoriametrics

I have Prometheus setup to scrape node_exporter from many Linux VMs. We have remote_write to VictoriaMetrics. But, now because of so many issues with Promethues resource requirements, I would like to move away from Prometheus and configure everything on Victoria Metrics.

I have installed victoria-metrics-k8s-stack and it is scraping all metrics from Kubernetes cluster and the node_exporters installed on Kubernetes nodes. But, How do configure VMAgent for my other targets (node_exporters) which are outside Kubernetes?

Tx,
Ab

Expecting something like flie_sd_config where list of targets can be added to Victoria Metrics.

Answer (score 3):

k8-stack use [VM operator](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/operator) under the box and that's why you need to use https://docs.victoriametrics.com/operator/additional-scrape.html#define-additional-scrape-configuration-as-a-kubernetes-secret for operator which will store your sd_config as asecret. See also operator docs: https://docs.victoriametrics.com/operator/

Comment: Hey @Denys Holius, Thanks for your prompt response. This works flawlessly!